# Textarea highlight on focus

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to have all the contents in a textarea highlight when it gains focus. Currently, as soon as it gains focus the contents will be highlighted but it immediately loses it.

This is what I'm using:

```
<textarea onfocus="this.select()" readonly>Test</textarea>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/spedwards/Mr2ja/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have prevent the mouseup event as well, as it fires after the focus is set and deselects the contents

```
<textarea onfocus="this.select()" onmouseup="return false;" readonly="readonly">Test</textarea>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mr2ja/5/)

Comment: This works though I have to ask, why did you change `onfocus` to `onfocusin`?

Comment: @Spedwards - Just a typo, I changed it to test something, but it's irrelevant, removed it.

Comment: Strange thing was it still worked. Makes me believe that `onfocusin` is an alternative which gives reason to believe `onfocusout` if existed could be an alternative to `onblur`

Comment: `onfocusout` exists, and is an alternative to `onblur`, the difference is in how they bubble up to the parents. You should generally stick with `focus` and `blur` unless you need delegation.