# Tab accessibility within a hover state

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, accessibility, jsx

I have a component that, upon a hover, shows a button and a link that you can click on. This is not a menu... just a box in the middle of the page.

For accessibility, I would like a user to be able to tab into the container (happens now, and displays the content in the `.HiddenUntilHover` class) AND also continue to tab to the button and link that show up on the hover/focused state.

Right now you can focus on the container and see the hover state; however, when you tab it just goes to the next element and does not allow you to tab to the button or link WITHIN the hover state.

Pseudo code example:

```html
/* My component .jsx */
<div tabIndex="0" className="MainContainer">
 <div className="SomeOtherClass">
   <div className="HiddenUntilHover">
     /* I would like to be able to tab to these clickable things! */
     <button>Click me!</button>
     <a href="...">I am also clickable</a>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

And my SCSS:

```css
.HiddenUntilHover {
  display: none;
}

MainContainer:focus,
MainContainer:hover,
> .HiddenUntilHover {
    display: block
}
```

Comment: I think you are missing a point (.) before `MainContainer`,  I think it should be like this `.MainContainer`. Right?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue a few days ago and I solved it using css classes to make the hovered content accessible via keyboard navigation.

The way I got this working was to use css pseudo-classes to ensure that when the `div` element is active & focused that the buttons inside also display. Specifically the additional use of `:focus-within` & `:focus-visible` should ensure that when you tab over the list items, their contents are also displayed and keyboard accessible.

```
.MainContainer  {
  &:not(:hover, :focus, :active, :focus-visible, :focus-within) {
    .HiddenUntilHover {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div tabIndex="0" className="MainContainer">
        Content
        <div className="SomeOtherClass">
          <div className="HiddenUntilHover">
            <button>Click me!</button>
            <a href="...">I am also clickable</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
```

#### Here's a link to the [Codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/accssible-tab-on-hover-hhy2f) of this working

Answer (score 1):

When the box is in focus, tabbing further to the button will make the box blur, which will hide it, and its contents, so focus will move to the next accessible element. I think this is the behavior you are experiencing.

You might consider using inserting an `aria-activedescendant` or `tabindex` attribute when the box comes into focus. This requires a little javascript.

Strictly speaking, you don't need to rely on the hover state to make that control accessible. You *could* have an offscreen (or clipped) button/link that is not a DOM child of the hidden (`display:none`) box. If you take this approach, read up on the `aria-owns` attribute.

As long as it is marked up as a button or link (or has a `tabindex="0"` setting), and is not 'really' hidden, it ought to be possible to tab to it.

Comment: if there is any example?

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the properties of the class `MainContainer`
for example.

```css
.MainContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
.MainContainer .HiddenUntilHover {
  display: none;
}
.MainContainer:hover .HiddenUntilHover, .MainContainer:focus .HiddenUntilHover {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Elements appearing on hover are inherently inaccessible. You are experiencing one side of the problem with your code, where it is difficult to make  it keyboard accessible.
But think about touch screens that have no real concept of hover: is there some way to reach your button on a smarphone or tablet?

For a more pragmatic answer, if you need to stay with hover, a less hacky solution than the two already posted ones could be the following:
use focusin and focusout events. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23114509/onfocus-vs-onfocusin-onblur-vs-onfocusout?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) for explanations and differences with focus/blur, and [this w3school doc](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocusin.asp) for browser compatibility.
You will have to structure your HTML differently, such as:

```
<div id="outer">
<div id="hover">
...
</div><!--hover-->
<button>Your button which only appears on hover</utton>
</div><!--outer-->
```

As well as use a bit of js:

```
$('#outer').on('focusin', __=>$('#hover').classNames.add('keep-visible'));
$('#outer').on('focusout', __=>$('#hover').classNames.remove('keep-visible'));
```

With a corresponding .keep-visible class which will leave the element display:block (I'm not a CSS expert, I let you write the code).

The overal functionning is the following: when some element within `#outer` takes the focus, the focusin element is fired due to bubbling. In the event, you put your class .keep-visible which makes the element to stay visible.
The focusout event is fired when the focus leaves the last element within `#outer`. At that point you remove the .keep-visible class, which makes the element to disappear.

According to the link above, onfocusin/out aren't standard, but are supported by all major browsers including IE. Firefox is the last one to implement it in 52.0, so it's a kind of defacto standard; we can reasonably expect that it won't disappear soon.