# Contact Form 7 - Adding placeholder to Date Field

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I've got two fields on a site to let users choose a date to pickup and return a rental vehicle.

I need a placeholder in both fields to indicate what information is required in each field.

I've followed the official advice **[here](https://contactform7.com/setting-placeholder-text/)**, by doing the below:

```
[date* FromDate placeholder "Start Date"]

[date* ToDate placeholder "Return Date"]
```

However, the result is simply the blank date.

[image]

The placeholder is present in the HTML code outputted too:

```
<input type="date" name="FromDate" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-date wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-date" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Start Date">
```

Comment: Refer https://contactform7.com/date-field/. It explains how to add placeholders in `date field`.

Comment: @user2584538 Sorry if I'm completely missing it, but I think that page just refers to the page I linked above which isn't working for me?

Comment: That reference has complete code `[date* your-date min:2013-01-01 max:2013-12-31 step:7 class:required "2013-04-01"]`

Comment: @user2584538 Again, perhaps I'm misunderstanding - but that doesn't appear to create a placeholder. If I copy and paste that exact code, it just sets restrictions on the dates that can be selected.

Comment: `"2013-04-01"` this is the placeholder text of above snippet. Ignore what you don't want like `min` and/or `max`.

Comment: @user2584538 Ahh I see what you mean. In the question I mentioned I wanted 'Start Date' as the placeholder, but your suggestion would just set a date as the placeholder.

Comment: @WPLearner that isn't a placeholder. That would be default value. They are different.

Answer (score 8):

Add this:

```
<input type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='text')"  name="FromDate" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-date wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-date" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Start Date">
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I add that to the shortcode though?

Comment: When editing the form via the Contact form 7 interface, you can simply replace the generated [date ... ] tag with this html directly.

Comment: this is not working in ios device
Please give me any solution

Comment: Any idea how to change the display format?

Comment: @ThomasMiller could you share the exact syntax of how you add it to {Date..} shortcode

Comment: Sorry @DebosmitMajumder, I don't remember where I used this.

Comment: @ThomasMiller @Dino The problem I am facing is I want to make it a required field and neither `aria-required` nor `required` works. 

It would be great if the html can be added as a Contact Form 7 tag wherein the `date*` or `text*` works as required.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this WordPress plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/date-time-picker-for-contact-form-7/

After you've installed and activated the plugin just add text field and add appropriate class:

```
[text EventDate class:walcf7-datepicker placeholder"Event date"]
```

Classes:
Only for Date Picker: `walcf7-datepicker`
Only for Time Picker: `walcf7-timepicker`
For both Date and Time Picker: `walcf7-datetimepicker`

Answer (score 0):

The answer from "Dino" (Feb 12 '19) works just fine. You would need to change the name="INSERTMAILDATENAME" to your datepickers name. In my instance the field was replaced with name="your-date". After making that modification it works just fine.  : o)

Answer (score 0):

This is just an update.

Using this:

```
<input type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='text')"  name="FromDate" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-date wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-date" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Start Date">
```

Fails when leaving the input i.e onblur

The code that worked for me is:

```
<input type="text" onfocusin="(this.type='date')" onfocusout="(this.type='text')"  name="FromDate" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-date wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-date" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Start Date">
```

i believe the onfocusout property was the only solution because of its bubbling property.

Read: [onfocus vs onfocusin & onblur vs onfocusout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23114509/onfocus-vs-onfocusin-onblur-vs-onfocusout)